# Way of graphic representation of Mean +/- SEM data

Tags: data-visualization

I have some experimental data (5-15) observations per group. I want to present it as mean $\pm$ SEM. I know 2 common ways to do it:
[image]

But, for some reasons, I want something else.

**Could You provide some examples of other styles to plot my data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why plot mean and SEM? 
With so few replicates, I suggest plotting a scatterplot showing the raw data.